# Problemas con caracteres especiales en un archivo XML creado con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

tengo un script en php que me genera un xml de unas tablas y parecía que me funcionaba correctamente, pero ahora uno de los valores de los campos tiene una "Ñ" y los navegadores me lo toman como error:

Error de lectura XML: mal formado

Número de línea 33, columna 36:         ARTURO CHAVEZ NUÑ

parte de mi código es este:

```
<?php


function crea_fichero($cadena){

    $flujo = fopen('club.xml', 'w');
    fputs($flujo, $cadena);
    fclose($flujo);
}


$opc = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba_importar";
$usuario = 'root';
$contrasena = '';

$dwes = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena, $opc);


if (isset($dwes)){

   $xml="<xml>\n";
   $xml.="\t<club>".date("d/m/Y")."</club>\n";

          $sql2="SELECT * FROM alumnos INNER JOIN (alumnosexamen INNER JOIN examen ON examen.claveexamen=alumnosexamen.claveexamen) ON alumnosexamen.claveweb= alumnos.claveweb AND alumnosexamen.clavealumno=alumnos.clavealumno WHERE examen.estatus='APROBADO' AND alumnos.clavealumno=0 ";


        echo '<br>';

        $cadena="alumnos";

        $xml .= "\t<".$cadena.">\n";
        $result= $dwes->query($sql2);

        $tamanio=strlen($cadena);
        $cadena2=substr($cadena,0,($tamanio-1));

        while($fila = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print_r($fila);

            $xml .= "\t\t<".$cadena2.">\n";

                        $clavealumno=utf8_decode($fila['clavealumno']);
                        $claveweb=utf8_decode($fila['claveweb']);
                        $claveescuela=utf8_decode($fila['claveescuela']);
                        $nombre=utf8_decode( $fila['nombre']);

                        $domicilio=utf8_decode($fila['domicilio']);
                        $ciudad=utf8_decode($fila['ciudad']);
                        $estado=utf8_decode($fila['estado']);
                        $telefono=utf8_decode( $fila['telefono']);

            $xml .= "\t\t</".$cadena2.">\n";
        }// while($fila
        $xml .= "\t</".$cadena.">\n";

    $xml .="</xml>";
crea_fichero($xml);
}//if(isset($dwes))
$result=null;
$dwes=null;

?>
```

Comment: puedes buscar informacion sobre la funcion de php Para estos casos es mejor usar:

utf8_decode($variable);

Comment: ¿Cómo creas el XML? Sería bueno que muestres el código de la función `crea_fichero`.

Answer (score 0):

En el código que muestras se puede ver que los datos que extraes son tratados como UTF8, ahora revisa que tu código para construir el XML también tenga en cuenta el uso de UTF8 ya sea a través de "" al inicio de tu archivo o indicandole la codificación UTF8 al objeto que estes utilizando para construir el XML.
Referencia 1: http://php.net/manual/es/sdo-das-xml.examples.php

Comment: Para que sea aceptada pon un ejemplo con el código que pusieron en la pregunta

Comment: como puedo teclear esto en PHP??    $xml="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n"; Así lo puse en mi script y no me funciona y la verdad ando dormido y no tengo idea de como ponerlo, disculpen mi ignorancia